# Extract text into string from html/javascript with php

Tags: php, html, regex, parsing, extract

I have a problem:
I have to extract text between
        "body":{"text":"
and
        ",".
This occurs 2 times in this example, those are comments from Facebook. I would like to extract and put text from between both criterias to single variable, delimited by newline. I'm using PHP, already got the whole HTML in variable named $html.

Here is the code:

```
[
   {
      "id":"537891442938686_1601777",
      "fbid":"537891612938669",
      "legacyid":"1601777",
      "body":{
         "text":"Jaaa:D",
         "ranges":[

         ],
         "aggregatedranges":[

         ]
      },
      "author":"1301211957",
      "ftentidentifier":"537891442938686",
      "likecount":0,
      "hasviewerliked":false,
      "canremove":false,
      "canreport":false,
      "canedit":false,
      "source":null,
      "istranslatable":false,
      "timestamp":{
         "time":1370411670,
         "text":"",
         "verbose":"4. junij 2013 ob 22:54"
      },
      "spamreplycount":0,
      "replyauthors":[

      ],
      "isfeatured":false
   },
   {
      "id":"537891442938686_1601790",
      "fbid":"537895309604966",
      "legacyid":"1601790",
      "body":{
         "text":"Takteri\u010d \u017ee sodelujem?? Hmm 5i\u010d?",
         "ranges":[

         ],
         "aggregatedranges":[

         ]
      },
      "author":"1087657810",
      "ftentidentifier":"537891442938686",
      "likecount":0,
      "hasviewerliked":false,
      "canremove":false,
      "canreport":false,
      "canedit":false,
      "source":null,
      "istranslatable":false,
      "timestamp":{
         "time":1370412832,
         "text":"",
         "verbose":"4. junij 2013 ob 23:13"
      },
      "spamreplycount":0,
      "replyauthors":[

      ],
      "isfeatured":false
   }
],
"profiles":[
   {
      "id":"1301211957",
      "name":"Maja Lamov\u0161ek",
      "firstName":"Maja",
      "vanity":"zmaychee",
      "thumbSrc":"https:\/\/fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net\/hprofile-ak-ash4\/s32x32"
   }
]
```

Thanks guys!!

Comment: search google for a function like `json_decode();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data you have there is in JSon format. I'd highly recommend decoding and putting it into an object. After that you can easily iterate through all the properties you need. Take a look at json_decode (http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Comment: thank you all, it was a messed up code in the source, sorry, i will chech json_decode